# Configuração do XML

Tags: php, postgresql, ubuntu, framework

Na configuração do pMapper (framework de Mapserver para PHP), existe esta configuração a qual estou em dúvida como configura-la.

`<dsn encoding="UTF-8">pgsql://postgres:postgres@localhost/db</dsn>`

Seria algo assim ?

```
<dsn encoding="UTF8">pgsql://[usuario]:[senha>@[localhost]/[banco]</dns>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, o teu exemplo está correto:

```
motorBD://<utilizador>:<password>@servidor/<nomeBaseDados>
```

**Exemplo:**

```
<dsn encoding="UTF-8">pgsql://postgres:postgres@localhost/gisdb</dsn>
<sql>SELECT DISTINCT name FROM cities1000 WHERE population > 10000 AND name ~* '^[search]' ORDER BY name</sql>
```

<sup>Exemplo em cima retirado da documentação em [pmapper - Attribute search](http://svn.pmapper.net/trac/wiki/DocManualsearch).</sup>

Comment: Pois é, estou tentando fazer funcionar este exemplo. Mas ele não fala que está OK e também não diz que tem erro. As vezes acho que ele dá um sorriso irônico e fala: 'Se vira negão, não quer ser programador ? Então toma!' =/

Comment: Me tira uma dúvida e se em `<dsn encoding="UTF8">pgsql://[usuario]:[senha>@[localhost]/[banco]</dns>` a senha possuir um caracter especial no início ou no fim, como por exemplo um **@**. Qual seria o correto: Aspas simples ou duplas ?